# how to check null value of a string and if it is null then suppress any table in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to suppress a sub-report.I want to check a string value either it is null or not.
If the string value is null then it will suppress.
I followed the following steps-

1. then I wrote a formula like

   if InStr ({EmployeeHist.SpouseName},'' ) = 0 then
           'N/A'

But its showing a error **THE FORMULA RESULT MUST BE A BOOLEAN**..

Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the formula to

ISNULL({EmployeeHist.SpouseName})

this will return true if the SpouseName is null and the subreport will be suppressed

Answer (score 0):

Change the formula like this

```
if InStr ({EmployeeHist.SpouseName},'' ) = '' then true else false
```